# Mustache.js Conditional Header

Tags: mustache

Using mustache.js, I only want to show a header (Colors) if the there are are actually values in the colors array.  One way that seems to be working is:

```
{colors: [] }

{{#colors.0}}<h1>Colors</h1>{{/colors.0}}

{{#colors}}
    * {{.}}
{{/colors}}
```

But it feels like there's a better way to do it.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's JavaScript you can use `{{# colors.length }}`, because that'll be truthy any time the array is non-empty.

Comment: Correct. However readers should be aware that this is a javascript-only technique (the two facts that `length` key is defined, and that the number zero is considered false). Cross-platform mustache templates would require an extra key such as `hasColors` which would hold a boolean.